# Error with rails g devise:views command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm new to rails and can't pinpoint the issue. I was following the RailsCast tutorial #209 about Devise and get an error when I run: rails g devise:views

Here is the error:

```
/Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:185:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `normalize_options!'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:61:in `initialize'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `new'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `add_route'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1284:in `decomposed_match'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `block in match'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `each'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `match'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:260:in `root'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1317:in `root'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/svn-work/gwb/trunk/PMOCCU/uidevise/config/routes.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/svn-work/gwb/trunk/PMOCCU/uidevise/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/svn-work/gwb/trunk/PMOCCU/uidevise/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/chanel.nalani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I changed the version of ruby to see if that would fix the issue but I haven't been able to find the exact problem. Did anybody else run into this error?

Comment: Could you give the config/routes.rb ?

Comment: What is your root route set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some manual setup that needs to be done(as @dougui and @janders223 pointed out, it's most likely your route), as printed on the console as soon as you finished running `rails generate devise:install` :

```
===============================================================================

Some setup you must do manually if you haven't yet:

  1. Ensure you have defined default url options in your environments files. Here 
     is an example of default_url_options appropriate for a development environment 
     in config/environments/development.rb:

       config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

     In production, :host should be set to the actual host of your application.

  2. Ensure you have defined root_url to *something* in your config/routes.rb.
     For example:

       root :to => "home#index"

  3. Ensure you have flash messages in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
     For example:

       <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
       <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

  4. If you are deploying Rails 3.1 on Heroku, you may want to set:

       config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

     On config/application.rb forcing your application to not access the DB
     or load models when precompiling your assets.

===============================================================================
```

Taken from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/README